Абстрактное свойство Python
При изучении абстрактного класса, я столкнулся с вопросом про абстрактное свойство класса родителя.
Пример кода:
import abc
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class parent(ABC):
    @abc.abstractproperty
    def someMethod(self):
        return "parent class"

class child(parent):
    @property
    def someMethod(self):
        return "child class"

try:
    obj = parent()
    print(obj.someMethod)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

obj = child()
print(obj.someMethod)

Результат:
Can't instantiate abstract class parent without an implementation for abstract method 'someMethod'
child class

Если мы используем @abstractproperty, то требуем атрибуты в родительском классе?
UPD: Судя по интерпретатору, мы можем создать экземпляр дочернего класса, но не родительского? Даже с одинаковой семантикой?

@abc.abstractproperty устарело, вообще-то редактор показывает такие подсказки. Пробуй к @property добавить еще @abstractmethod вместо @abstractproperty

@AlexanderLonberg мой IDE это Atom и не вижу никаких подсказок в таких моментах)

Вместо @abc.abstractproperty использовал @abstractmethod, результат остался тем же

Как я понял, мы не можем создать экземпляр родительского класса, однако создается экземпляр дочернего класса, который имеет одинаковую семантику.  Также можем использовать вызов метода из родительского класса, используя super.

Конечно ты не можешь создать класс с абстрактным свойством или методом. Если тебе нужен вызов из дочернего класса, то зачем тебе абстрактный метод? Абстрактный предполагает только сигнатуру без реализации. PS: если твой ID не показывает устаревание abstractproperty перейди к определению и увидишь там такую строку Deprecated, use 'property' with 'abstractmethod'

Ну да, абстрактный метод - не реализованный метод. Класс без реализации абстрактного метода нельзя инстанциировать. Всё логично.

Используя декоратор @abstractmethod перед определенным методом, мы указываем, что данный метод родительского класса является абстрактным и требует реализации со стороны дочернего класса. Также указав декоратор @property, мы можем преобразовать метод в свойство класса.
Пример использования декоратора @abstractmethod без реализации в дочернем классе:
import abc
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod #декоратор, который указывает, что "someMethod" главный метод в супер классе
    def someMethod(self):
        return "parent class"

class child(parent):
     pass #нет переопределения супер метода

obj = child()
print(obj.someMethod)

Результат:
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class child without an implementation for abstract method 'someMethod'

Пример использования декоратора @abstractmethod с реализацией метода в дочернем классе:
import abc
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def someMethod(self):
        return "parent class"

class child(parent):
    def someMethod(self):
        return "child class"

obj = child()
print(obj.someMethod())

Результат:
child class

Использование @property:
print(obj.someMethod)

Без декоратора:
print(obj.someMethod())


Правильнее будет не переопределение а реализация. И абстрактному методу не нужно тело функции, там обычно raise или просто три точки ...

@AlexanderLonberg разве raise не для исключений? для методов подойдет pass

Да, именно. Можно просто pass. Три точки удобно когда нет описания, так как их можно написать в одной строке some(self) -> str:... - вот так выглядит самое краткое описание в одной строке.

Что значит обратную совместимость? Если твой код собирается работать в устаревших версиях Python не поддерживающие аннотации, то конечно не используй. Только все популярные библиотеки обычно обновляют под стабильные версии. А версия 3.12 поддерживает практически все.
